# Wait in main thread in android

Tags: android, synchronization

I am trying to create an app which plays music first when the app is opened and after the music is played the rest of the code is executed. Right now I am doing something as below:

```
MusicPlayer mp=new MusicPlayer();
mp.setDataSource("source");
mp.prepare();
mp.start();

do {

} while(mp.isPlaying());
```

I am just idling system with the do-while loop but I think the system is getting overloaded due to this and the emulator is also getting stuck due to this.

Is there any effective way to do this?

Comment: Can't you create a callback on MusicPlayer class for when it finish playing?

Comment: `I think the system is getting overloaded` the CPU is running at 100% on the core your busy loop is running on... there's no "think" about it, you're stealing CPU cycles from other code that may actually make use of them. There are several alternatives, and a callback if available is the best one.

Comment: What do you mean by callback on musicplayer--any example.?

Comment: A good general rule is to never wait in the gui thread. A locked gui is a source of major frustration for the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to do is the right thing. If you block the UI thread and nothing is happening but only some music is playing, the users may feel as something is wrong and doesn't work properly.

It would be better your music to play while something is happening - splash is shown, content is downloading, or something else.

Use [`myPlayer.setOnCompletionListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener%29) as @Manu said to call the event/method which has to be executed after the music is completed. You have to do something like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private MusicPlayer mp;

    protected void onCreate(...) {
        super.onCreate(...);
        mp = new MusicPlayer();
        mp.setDataSource("source");
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(
            new OnCompletionListener() {

                onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) {
                    otherMethod();                     
                }

            });
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume(); 
        playMusic();
    }

    private void playMusic() {
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    }

    // Called when the music is finished.
    private void otherMethod() {
        // Do something.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a callback function, called CompletionListener. You can set it with:

```
myPlayer.setOnCompletionListener
```

You can find the describtion here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#Callbacks